# Disable auto overlay prompt in AUCTeX?

Tags: auctex, beamer

Is there any way of disabling `AUCTeX` from auto-promping for optional overlay options in a `Beamer` document? I use global overlay options, and the prompting for local ones can be annoying when writing long documents.

Comment: Just for `\item`?  In that case set `LaTeX-beamer-item-overlay-flag` to nil.

Comment: Thanks. Please make this an answer and I will approve it.

Comment: Where did you find that option? I couldn't find it in the official documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order not to be prompted anymore for overlay specification in `\item` like macros, set the variable `LaTeX-beamer-item-overlay-flag` to nil.  You can do it locally or globally, for the latter case customize that variable or add this code to your init file:

```
(setq LaTeX-beamer-item-overlay-flag nil)
```

As most style-specific options, this variable is not documented in the official manual of AUCTeX, but you can find them browsing `customize-group` <kbd>RET</kbd> `LaTeX-style` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

Comment: I've changed something in auctex (can't remember what) to add the frame and minted environments with C-c C-e, and unfortunately, this annoying thing started popping up as well. Great that there is a solution.